# Is there a way to contact a person who voted to close a question

Tags: discussion, support, closing, notifications

I typically put 20-30 minutes into each of my questions to make sure they are as clear possible.

Someone recently voted to close my question because they felt the question wasn’t clear and didn’t leave a comment.

I really appreciate when someone tells me a question is unclear.  This is an opportunity for me to think through my assumptions and hopefully improve the quality of my posts over all.

I spent 20 minutes revising the question with the hope that I had addressed the concerns of the person who voted to close my question.

Is there any way to notify them?  Ideally, I’d love to see the question unflagged, a comment, or an indication that the question is still not clear.

Thanks very much,

-Larry

Comment: Presuming that you are referring to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132788/is-this-argument-a-valid-use-of-inductive-proof), you might want to consider the thought that *more* is not necessarily *better*.  It seems that your basic question is "Can an induction proof be valid without a base case?"  Adding *some* context to that question is good, but you have written so much that it is a bit hard to see what, exactly, you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I was worried that might be the case.  I will work on simplifying the question and reducing its length.

Comment: This may be small comfort, but - one person voting to close a question has no real effect; it takes four people to actually close it. The best you can do is to try to leave a polite request comment (something like "If you voted to close, I would be glad to improve the question, could you let me know your concerns?").  There is no way to force them to respond, but sometimes that kind of comment will get a response or get feedback from others, if it doesn't come off as argumentative.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I had not known the impact of a single vote to close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to contact users that vote to close your questions, especially not before the vote took effect.

It is possible to contact users that cast a binding vote on your  question (note that the vote needs to be the only vote that created the effect), that is a moderator or a user with a gold-badge in the tag that marked your post as a duplicate. Use the usual comment-notify mechanism.

The same is true for downvotes.

There are long-standing feature request for such things, but it seems they are not picked up on for fear of such features getting misused or them creating more friction.

Comment: Thanks.  I think it would be valuable in the future to indicate that a revision has occurred since a vote or flag was posted.

Comment: I think may share that sentiment see [this very old and popular request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c).

Comment: Perhaps it is worth stressing that users casting binding votes (a moderator or a user with [dupehammer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/dupehammer/info)) can be pinged only if no other users cast close vote before them - they closed the vote singlehandedly. This is mentioned both [in the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) and in [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277312/no-notification-for-comment-reply-when-using-dupe-hammer-along-with-other-close/310869#310869) to a related question.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I did not know that. I added a remark.